# Laptop doesn't automatically wake upon lid opening

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, acpi

To be clear, S3 works just fine on my laptop. When I close my laptop lid, my laptop enters suspend, but if I open the lid, I have to press a key before the laptop wakes. How can I force the laptop to automatically wake from sleep after opening the lid?

Here's my /proc/acpi/wakeup:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *disabled
XHC   S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
```

This is my /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state:

```
state:      open
```

So, it *appears* my laptop switch state is being read correctly, but I just don't get why my laptop won't automatically wake.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?